# Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0] on object of type:

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i have problim when trying to run flutter run in cmd

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "xx\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'xx\android\app\build.gradle' line: 61
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0] on object of type
  >   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

}
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    }
```

gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

Answer (score 6):

In your `app/build.gradle` you have **to remove** these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'  //to be removed
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'  //to be removed
}
```

In your `build.gradle` (main folder) you have **to add** in the `buildscript` block :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        //... others
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // others...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look into this question I tried to solve it but could not solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513672/errorunable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebugandroidtest-compileclasspath @Gabriele Mariotti